# Set a default value when ng-repeat finds a null or undefined in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am fairly new to AngularJS and I am trying to have my ng-repeat set a default value when a null is found. I tried this solution which I found on another SO page,

```
<div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat="data in dataNames">
    {{data.name || '<b>NONE</b>'}}
</div>
```

However when I add in the NONE text it is just displaying the whole line as plain text and it appears angular is not evaluating it.

**UPDATE**

I am trying to call this filter now and use $sce to allow me to return html. Here is the filter

```
require(["app", "angular"], function(app, angular) {
    app.filter("default", function ($sce) {
        return function (input, def) { 
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(!!input ? input : '<b>' + def + '</b>');
        };
    });
});
```

And here is how I am calling it

```
{{ name | default: 'NONE' }}
```

It is calling the function and evaluating correctly, but it is displaying the b tags as plain text instead of html. Am I not using $sce correctly maybe?

Comment: you cannot use html tags in the expression. You'll have to create a function and use [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) to return the value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is equivalent to your first attempt.  `ng-if` only produces a `b` tag when the name is null or undefined.

```
<div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat="data in dataNames">
  {{data.name}}<b ng-if="!data.name">NONE</b>
</div>
```

Here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/heRkCMvuqCHbyJhgpV4p?p=preview

Comment: So I guess there is no simple solution like the one I was trying?

Comment: No, not if you're trying to insert tags.  remove the `b` tags and your code should be fine.  angular has plenty of nice ways of adding style conditionally, if you need it to be bold.

Comment: @Metropolis this seems the easiest solution and +1 to using ng-class to bold it.

Comment: @Ronnie Yeah it seems easy, just feels kind of hackish to me. But maybe I will just roll with this. The other problem is I am going to have to reuse this many many times because much of the data I have has null values. It would be cumbersome to have to do this every time.

Comment: It isn't hackish. It is just another way of doing it. I'd prefer this method over all the others. Simplest IMO

Comment: @Ronnie Even if I have to do this over and over?

Comment: @Metropolis if you find yourself doing it a lot, a custom directive would make sense.

Comment: @j.wittwer Yeah I was thinking that the filter would work. Do you know how to get the code working that I put in my update? Nobody else seems to be answering about that. But it feels close.

Comment: That really isnt a very `angular` solution.  Write a directive to modify the DOM, or use something built in like ng-show and ng-style.  If I get time later I'll post a directive that does this.

Comment: @j.wittwer Okay ill see if I can come up with something. It amazes me that nobody has run into this problem before? Seems like it would come up often.

Comment: @Metropolis added much simpler solution.  turns out the first `ng-show` for data with a name was not necessary.  i think this is now simple enough that custom solutions are not warranted.

Answer (score 2):

In one of my project, I defined my 'default' filter:

```
angular.module('my.filters', []).
    filter('default',[function ()
    {
        return function (input, def)
        {
            return !!input ? input : def;
        };
    }]);
```

Include it to your code (file and dependency) and you can use it as

```
{{ data.name | default:'NONE' }}
```

However, if you want to use HTML as the value, you need to do more, for example

```
<div ng-bind-html="{{ data.name | default:'<b>NONE</b>' }}" ...></div>
```

You may need to include the angular-sanitize.js module for the above to work.
An alternative is to use ng-style or ng-class for making the text bold:

```
    <div ng-class="{'bold':data.name}" >{{ data.name | default:'NONE' }}</div>
```

Comment: How would I do this if there are multiple variables inside the repeat? Such as `<div ng-repeat="name in names">{{value}} - {{value}}</div>`

Comment: I wonder if I could use the $sce variable as Ronnie has above and add that to the filter.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use HTML tags, you'll have to use [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24sce)

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/poculaku/1/)

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="data in dataNames" ng-bind-html="formatName(data.name)"></li>
</ul>
```

Controller:

```
function TestController($scope, $sce)
{
  $scope.dataNames = [
    {
      foo: 'bar',
      name: 'Ronnie'
    },
    {
      foo: 'bar',
      name: 'Ted'
    },
    {
      foo: 'bar',
      name: null
    },
    {
      foo: 'bar',
      name: 'Jason'
    }
  ];

  $scope.formatName = function(name)
  {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml((name != null) ? name : '<b>none</b>');
  }
}
```

OutPut:

- Ronnie
- Ted
- **none**
- Jason

Comment: I cant get this to call the function. I added the ngSanitize module to the controller also. I am using a newer version of Angular. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across the same problem recently and ended up using a custom filter. While this does have the downside of a bit more work upfront, the solution can be used in similar situations and lets you substitute different text.

So the expression would look like this: `{{variable || nullFilter:'This value is null'}}`

The filter looked similar to:

```
angular.module('appName').filter('nullFilter', function() {
return function(input, replacementText) {

  if (input == null) {
    return replacementText;
  }
  return input;
};
```

});

More documentation can be found here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted. Its almost the same as most of the other answers here.

Answer (score 0):

As https://stackoverflow.com/users/1245971/j-wittwer. shows one way(using ng-if) but we can implement this by using angularjs filter

{{data.name||'---Null'}} --> By writing this we can show '---Null' when  ng-repeat finds a null or undefined in angularjs

I have created plunkr of using both ng-if and angular filter.

Now its on your choice what you like.